# jquery conflict when using slide gallery

Tags: jquery, slider, conflict

I am not able to call function on button click when using slider gallery. When I remove all slider content from my project then it works fine.

```
    var dec_Options=[];
    var dec_Details=[];


    window.onload = function(){
        // fix height width of screen....
        var width=(parseInt($(document).width()));  
        var height=(parseInt($(window).height()));
        $('body').css({'height': height,'width':width});
        $('#page').css({'height': height,'width':width});       
    }   


    $(document).ready(function (){

       //slider initialize............
        $("#slider").easySlider({

                    continuous: true,
                    nextId: "slider1next",
                    prevId: "slider1prev"
        });


   //get data from ajax..............       
     syncDecorationDetails(function(decoOption,decoDetails){
        dec_Options = decoOption;
        //alert('inside------'+dec_Options);
        //options=dec_Options;
        dec_Details = decoDetails;
    }); 




 });


    //on click function called when button clicks...........
    function loadGalleryImage(){
         alert('fd');
    }
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    script src="js/syncData.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

// below script added is the file showqn above.............
    <script src="js/decor.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
//.........................

    <script type="text/javascript" src="sliderjs/easySlider1.7.js"></script>


<link href="css/screen.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="content">  
        <div id="slider">
            <ul>                
                <li><img src="chori1.jpg" /></a></li>
                <li><img src="chori2.jpg" /></a></li>

            </ul>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
<div>   
<button onclick="loadGalleryImage()">Try it</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

now if i am adding one more button inside div before this button then it works fine button only outside the div not  the one in div.

```
<div id="decorationSelection" >
        <button onclick="loadGalleryImage()"></button>
</div>  
//...this button below work  but f  the above code of div and button inside is  there 
 <button onclick="loadGalleryImage()">Try it</button>
```

Comment: [You shouldn't add greetings or salutations to your posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Why do you need _jquery-1.8.2.js_ and _jquery-1.8.3.js_ together..? They will make conflict.

Answer (score 0):

The error is here ->

```
// below script added is the file showqn above.............
<script src="js/decor.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
//.........................
<script type="text/javascript" src="sliderjs/easySlider1.7.js"></script>
```

You said that `decor.js` is the file that references the `easySlider` function. However, you don't load the easySlider script until *after* you call it. This will never work. Simply place the easySlider script *above* the decor script, and you'll no longer receive an error in your console about the lack of the easySlider function.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="sliderjs/easySlider1.7.js"></script>
<script src="js/decor.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

That's how it should look.

Comment: easy slider is the js file for slider component only and where decoer.js is the one where i have coded my stuff and even initialised that slider componenet

Comment: @unkown In the order you have the files, you call the `.easySlider()` function. I see it, but that code runs *before* you actually load the `easySlider1.7.js` file. If the file that creates the plugin called `easySlider` is not included when you attempt to initialize it, then it won't work. Do what I said, and you'll be fine. trust me.

Comment: now if i am adding one more button  inside div before this button then it works how is this possible can u guide me